# Como remover palavras entre chaves { } no campo em Mysql?

Tags: mysql, sql, tabela-banco-de-dados, replace

Tenho uma tabela que contém um campo com alguns valores entre chaves, como faço para excluir as `chaves` e os `valores` que estão dentro delas?

Exemplo:

```
 cod | Movimento            |

 01  | Prazos {aguardando}  |
```

`Prazos {aguardando}` deverá virá isto: `Prazos`. Ou seja, remover `{conteudo}`

Quero apagar essas chaves e os caracteres que se encontram dentro dela. Como faço isso?

Answer (score 3):

***Faça:***

```
SELECT LOCATE('{', SEUCAMPO), LOCATE('}', SEUCAMPO)
FROM SUATABELA;


SELECT SUBSTRING(SEUCAMPO,LOCATE('{', SEUCAMPO), LOCATE('}', SEUCAMPO))
FROM SUATABELA;


SELECT REPLACE(SEUCAMPO,SUBSTRING(SEUCAMPO,LOCATE('{', SEUCAMPO), LOCATE('}', SEUCAMPO)),'')
FROM SUATABELA;
```

## [SqlFIddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/f0bb3d/6)

Não é necessário o `1º` e `2º SELECT`, é apenas uma demonstração de como cada função irá retornar seu valor. Separei o `Fiddle` para que você possa entender melhor como funciona todo o processo, *explicando*:

- Encontre a posição de `{` e `}` usando a função [`LOCATE`](https://www.w3resource.com/mysql/string-functions/mysql-locate-function.php).
- Através da posição utilize [`SUBSTRING`](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/func_mysql_substring.asp) para extrair a parte que deseja remover.
- Agora basta utilizar a função [`REPLACE`](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/func_mysql_replace.asp), substituindo por `''`.

***Nota:*** Para que essa solução funcione em `MSSQL` basta trocar a função `LOCATE` por `CHARINDEX`, ambas são equivalentes.