# Filtrar dados tabela

Tags: sql-server

Como selecionar apenas parte do registro de uma tabela?

Dados de origem:

```
"brt_qsr01:NT"
```

e eu pretendia que retornasse apenas `qsr01`

Estou fazendo assim, mas depois não consigo remover os dados à esquerda

```
  SELECT left([coluna], CHARINDEX(':', [coluna]) -1 ) FROM [dbo].[tabela]
```

Comment: A um tempo atrás respondi essa: [Como remover palavras entre chaves { } no campo em Mysql?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/256714/como-remover-palavras-entre-chaves-no-campo-em-mysql/256724#256724) que se parece muito com o que deseja!

Comment: E qual é a regra para retirar o prefixo, de modo que fique somente `qsr01`?

Answer (score 0):

Para esse caso em especifico, você poderia fazer assim:

```
SELECT substring( nome_coluna, 5, 5 ) FROM tabela
```

Mas se as posições forem diferentes de registro para registro, você precisa aplicar uma regra inteligente. Se for o caso, poste maiores informações para que possamos ajuda-lo.

Answer (score 0):

Obrigado pelas dicas

Resolveu o problema

```
DECLARE @teste varchar(100)
SET     @teste = '"brt_qsr01:NT"' 


select SUBSTRING(@teste,CHARINDEX('_',@teste)+1,CHARINDEX(':',@teste)-CHARINDEX('_',@teste)-1)
```

Devolve só a string ue pretendo: qsr01